# Live Stream browser audio to Google Speech-to-Text conversion using SignalR in .NET and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, signalr, speech-to-text

I have a voice ordering app, and currently, the push-to-talk button is functioning well. It records the audio, and we send that file to Google for speech-to-text processing. Now, I want to add a streaming option to send the microphone audio directly to Google for live speech-to-text. The technology stack for this includes SignalR, JavaScript, and Google Speech-to-Text. I've implemented the basic code, but when I send the stream to Google, it consistently returns a blank result.

I have below java script which is streaming audio and sending that to signalR hub as a base64.

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/speechHub").configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();

function webaudio_tooling_obj() {

    var audioContext = new AudioContext();

    console.log("audio is starting up ...");

    var buffSize = 16384;

    var audioInput = null,
        microphoneStream = null,
        gainNode = null,
        scriptProcessorNode = null,
        scriptProcessorFftNode = null,
        analyzerNode = null;

    if (!navigator.getUserMedia)
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {

        navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true },
            function (stream) {
                startMicrophone(stream);
            },
            function (e) {
                alert('Error capturing audio.');
            }
        );

    } else { alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.'); }

    connection.start().then(function () {

    }).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });

    function encodeBytesToBase64(bytes) {
        // Convert byte array to binary string
        const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(bytes);
        const base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uint8Array));
        console.log("base64String " + base64String);
        return base64String;
    }

    function convertFloat32ArrayToBytes(float32Array) {
        const bytes = new Uint8Array(float32Array.length * 4);

        for (let i = 0; i < float32Array.length; i++) {
            const floatValue = float32Array[i];
            const bytesOffset = i * 4;

            // Assuming little-endian byte order
            const byteArray = new Float32Array([floatValue]);
            const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(byteArray.buffer);

            bytes.set(uint8Array, bytesOffset);
        }

        return bytes;
    }
    function float32ArrayToBlob(float32Array) {
        const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(float32Array.length * 2);
        const view = new DataView(buffer);
        float32Array.forEach((value, index) => {
            view.setInt16(index * 2, value * 0x7FFF, true);
        });

        // Create a Blob with the ArrayBuffer
        const blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'audio/wav' });
        return blob;
    }

    // Assume 'blob' is your audio blob
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function () {
        const base64String = reader.result.split(',')[1];
        console.log(base64String);

        // Now you can send the base64String to the server using SignalR
        sendBase64ToServer(base64String);
    };


    function process_microphone_buffer(event) { // invoked by event loop
        var microphone_output_buffer = event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
        var blob = float32ArrayToBlob(microphone_output_buffer);
        //var dataAsInt16Array = convertFloat32ArrayToBytes(microphone_output_buffer);
        //console.log("dataAsInt16Array " + dataAsInt16Array);
        //var byteArray = new Int8Array(dataAsInt16Array.buffer);
        //console.log("byteArray " + byteArray);
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

    }

    function sendBase64ToServer(base64String) {
        connection.invoke("SendMicrophoneBuffer", base64String).catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        });
    }

    connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (message) {
        console.log(message);
    });

    function startMicrophone(stream) {

        gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
        gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

        microphoneStream = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        microphoneStream.connect(gainNode);

        scriptProcessorNode = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(buffSize, 1, 1);
        scriptProcessorNode.connect(gainNode);
        scriptProcessorNode.onaudioprocess = process_microphone_buffer;

        microphoneStream.connect(scriptProcessorNode);

        // --- enable volume control for output speakers

        document.getElementById('volume').addEventListener('change', function () {

            var currVolume = this.value;
            gainNode.gain.value = currVolume;

        });

        //  --- setup FFT

        scriptProcessorFftNode = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
        scriptProcessorFftNode.connect(gainNode);

        analyzerNode = audioContext.createAnalyser();
        analyzerNode.smoothingTimeConstant = 0;
        analyzerNode.fftSize = 2048;

        microphoneStream.connect(analyzerNode);

        analyzerNode.connect(scriptProcessorFftNode);

        scriptProcessorFftNode.onaudioprocess = function () {

            // get the average for the first channel
            var array = new Uint8Array(analyzerNode.frequencyBinCount);
            analyzerNode.getByteFrequencyData(array);

            //// draw the spectrogram
            //if (microphoneStream.playbackState == microphoneStream.PLAYING_STATE) {

            //    showSomeData(array, 5, "from fft");
            //}
        };
    }

};
```

Here is C# where I am sending stream to google .

```
public class SpeechHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly IGoogleTextToSpeechService _googleTextToSpeechService;

        public SpeechHub(IGoogleTextToSpeechService googleTextToSpeechService)
        {
            _googleTextToSpeechService = googleTextToSpeechService;
        }

        public async Task SendMicrophoneBuffer(string base64AudioData)
        {

            var byteData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64AudioData);
             
            RecognizeResponse? response = await _googleTextToSpeechService.SynthesizeSpeechAsync(byteData);
            if (response != null && response.Results.Count > 0 && response.Results.Any(x => x.Alternatives.Count > 0))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response);
            }

            //await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", response);

        }

    }
```

```
public async Task<RecognizeResponse?> SynthesizeSpeechAsync(byte[] audio)
        {

            var streamingCall = _speechClient.StreamingRecognize();

            await streamingCall.WriteAsync(
                new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
                {
                    StreamingConfig = new StreamingRecognitionConfig()
                    {
                        Config = new RecognitionConfig()
                        {
                            Encoding =
                                RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.WebmOpus,
                            SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                            LanguageCode = LanguageCodes.English.UnitedStates,
                        },
                        InterimResults = true,
                    }
                });

            Task printResponses = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var resultsAsyncResponseStream = streamingCall.GetResponseStream();

                if (resultsAsyncResponseStream != null && resultsAsyncResponseStream.Current != null && resultsAsyncResponseStream.Current.Results != null)
                    foreach (var result in resultsAsyncResponseStream.Current.Results)
                    {
                        foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(alternative.Transcript);
                        }
                    }
            });

            await streamingCall.WriteAsync(
                new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
                {
                    AudioContent = Google.Protobuf.ByteString
                        .CopyFrom(audio, 0, audio.Length),
                });
            await Task.Delay(500);


            await streamingCall.WriteCompleteAsync();
            await printResponses;

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are sending small buffer and it is not enough to actually recognize something?